# Representability of $\operatorname{Hom}(G_{\mathbb{Q}}, \operatorname{GL}_2)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations, representable-functors

Let $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the absolute Galois group of the rationals, and let $F: \mathrm{Aff}/\textbf{Q}_p\longrightarrow \mathrm{Sets}$ be the functor which associates to every affine $\mathbb{Q}_p$ scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ the set of representations $\operatorname{Hom}(G_{\mathbb{Q}}, \operatorname{GL}_2(A))$.

Is this functor representable?

Comment: Representable by a scheme? This seems hopeless since the pushout of rings need not induce a pushout of GL2 in groups.